# to_json in pyspark is exluding null values, but I need the null values as blank

Tags: python, struct, pyspark, azure-databricks, to-json

I am converting a struct column in dataframe to json column using to_json in pyspark, but null values in few of the struct fields are ignored in json, I dont want the null values to be ignored.

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 6):

When reading the official documentation for [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html), it says :

> **options** dict, optional
> options to control converting. accepts the same options as the JSON datasource. See [Data Source Option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html#data-source-option) for the version you use. Additionally the function supports the pretty option which enables pretty JSON generation.

Following the link, there is an option `ignoreNullFields` that you can try setting to `False`:

```py
pyspark.sql.functions.to_json(col, options={"ignoreNullFields":False})
```

Test is on your side because you did not provide any **Minimal, Reproducible Example**.